# Scheme how to define var in if condition

Tags: scheme, racket

I am  newbie to Scheme programming and trying to define a var in if condition. For example, I have:

```
(if (< x y) (define x y) ) ;(GOAL: if x < y, than x=y..)
```

But I got the error:

```
let: bad syntax (not an identifier and expression for a binding) in:...
```

Any ideas how to resolve this, would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. Sorry for my English

Comment: Maybe you could add a little more context, because this looks very un-schemish ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using define is wrong; you are not defining a function here. There are two solutions:

```
(if (< x y) (set! x y) (void)) ; if x < y set x = y; else do nothing
```

Or

```
(set! x (if (< x y) y x))      ; sets x to y if (x<y) is true; else sets x to x
```

Comment: `define` can be used for any binding, not only functions

Comment: The alternative is optional in R6RS Scheme so `(if (< x y) (set! x y))` is legal.

Comment: @Sylwester It's not optional in Racket though.

Comment: @sepp2k True. Some R5RS restrictions are kept in #!racket.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike imperative languages you should refrain not use `define` or `set!` to update variables where you can avoid it. In some circumstances it's needed, like in generators.
Since you don't have a full code example where you'd like to do this I cannot see what obvious solution is to be used.

The way to store intermediate values if by `let` or recursion:

```
;; within the let block x shadows the original x 
;; with the smalles of the outer x and y
(let ((x (if (< x y) x y)))
    (do-something x))
```

You can do several intermediates by `let*`

```
(let* ((tmp (+ x y))
       (tmp2 (* tmp y))) ; tmp is bound here
  (do-something-with tmp2)); or tmp and tmp2
```

You you can use recursion, where you update cur and lst in th innner procedure by recursion:

```
(define (mmin x . xs)
  (define (min-aux cur lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) cur)
          ((<= cur (car lst)) (min-aux cur (cdr lst)))
          (else (min-aux (car lst) (cdr lst)))))

  (min-aux x xs)) ; start recursion
```

It is an error to `define` something that is already defined so thats why I defined

If you need to do this top level you can:

```
(define min_xy (if (< x y) x y))
```

`min_xy`. To alter a binding destructively (get it to reference another value) you can use `set!`

```
(set! x (+ x 1)) ; increases x
```

You'll alter the most local definition and it's an error if it doesnæt already exist. This can be used for creating generators:

```
(define (generator start alter-proc)
  (lambda ()                           ; returns a procedure taking 0 arguments
    (let ((old start))                 ; temporary store what start points to
       (set! start (alter-proc start)) ; change what the local start points to
       old)))                          ; return the old value     

(define counter (generator 1 (lambda (x) (+ x 1))))
(counter) ; ==> 1
(counter) ; ==> 2

(define doubler (generator 1 (lambda (x) (* x 2))))
(doubler) ; ==> 1
(doubler) ; ==> 2
(doubler) ; ==> 4
```

Comment: I understand discouraging `set!` -- but not `define`, which, like `let`, simply lets you create a binding. In fact in Racket `define` is  often encouraged vs. `let` to reduce "rightward drift" indentation. But even if you don't like that style of _preferring_ `define`, I don't understand _discouraging_ it?

Comment: @GregHendershott I discurage it just for updating bindings. Many implementations support such use even if it's not correct Scheme. Using `define` to define globals or in procedures (where it works as `letrec`) is of course ok.

Comment: @Sylwester OK I see. FWIW in Racket something like `(begin (define x 1) (define x 2))` is an error in a module (file): "module: duplicate definition for identifier at: x".  Of course the REPL is another matter. :)

Comment: @GregHendershott Racket and Ikarus are the exceptions. It works as `set!` in Chibi-scheme, Chicken, Gambit, Guile, and Stalin. All standard conformant since it should never happen in a source file.