# Define inside an if

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I've just started to learn Racket.

I have this code:

```
#lang racket

(define t1 '(10 20))
(define t2 '(20 30))

(if (list? (first t1)) (define funcion1 >=) (define funcion1 >))
(if (list? (last t1)) (define funcion2 <=) (define funcion2 <))

(not (and (function1 (first t2) (first t1))
          (function2 (last t2) (last t1))))
```

But it doesn't work because Racket doesn't allow this: `(define funcion1 >=)`. I get the error:

> define: not allowed in an expression context in: (define funcion1 >=)

Instead of doing nested if, I have thought to use a generic id (**function1** and **function2**) for the function `>` and `<`.

**NOTE**:
 `t1` could be also`(define t1 '((20) 35))`.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`define` is **different** top level and inside a function. Also while you cannot put `define` in side a `if` you can put `if` inside the expression of a `define`:

This is totally OK:

```scm
(define function1 (if (list? (first t1)) >= >))
(define function2 (if (list? (last t1)) <= <))
```

Using `let` is also OK, but then you can only them withing the closure it creates:

```scm
(let ([function1 (if (list? (first t1)) >= >)]
      [function2 (if (list? (last t1)) <= <)])
  ;; use function1 and function2 here
  )
;; function1 and function2 no longer exists here
```

Same with local `define`:

```scm
(let () ;; this is a function called right away
  ;; these are local define
  (define function1 (if (list? (first t1)) >= >))
  (define function2 (if (list? (last t1)) <= <))

  ;; use function1 and function2 here
  )
;; function1 and function2 no longer exists here
```

This is just fancy way of writing:

```scm
(let ()
  (letrec ([function1 (if (list? (first t1)) >= >)]
           [function2 (if (list? (last t1)) <= <)])
    ;; use function1 and function2 here
    )
  ;; use function1 and function2 here
  )
```

The `let` in the last example is redundant and just there because the previous example had it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found how to fix this problem with the inspiration of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19743220/68571): using [let](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html).

```
#lang racket

(define t1 '(10 20))
(define t2 '(20 30))

(let ([function1 (if (list? (first t1)) >=  >)])
(let ([function2 (if (list? (last t1)) <= <)])

(not (and (function1 (first t2) (first t1))
          (function2 (last t2) (last t1))))))
```

But maybe there is a better way to do it.